# I need a validation rule which will throw an error based on Profile

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Requirement:I need a validation rule which will throw an error When `City=blank and User Profile =System administartor OR Solution manager`.

Below is my Validation

```
AND(NOT(OR($Profile.Name = " System Administrator ", $Profile.Name = "Solution manager ")),ISBLANK(City))
```

But its firing even though i am editing record using different profile

Comment: Remove the not part. You want it to evaluate to true to throw validation error

Comment: Thank Eric. When I Removed NOT then for above 2 profiles validation is not getting fired.But i need validation fire for only above two profiles

Comment: Then something you are doing might be incorrect. Start with a rule that just checks the one profile name, test it, add another criteria,test,etc. when it breaks figure out why. Basic troubleshooting. Removing the not should have worked unless I am reading it wrong. Also ensure city is indeed blank

Comment: Check for space while evaluating profile name ($Profile.Name = "System Administrator")

Comment: You are adding extra space with both profile names remove spaces and then try;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the validation rule only for two profile then remove Not from condition.

```
AND(OR($Profile.Name = "System Administrator", $Profile.Name = "Solution manager"),ISBLANK(City))
```

Comment: Why you only removed space from " System Administrator" profile?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I didn't notice space in end. Thanks.